# Solution to nonlinear ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Find all solutions the to initial value problem $$\frac{dy}{dx}=y^3e^{\sin{(x+y^2)}}, \quad y(2020)=0$$ and explain why there are no other solutions.
So there exists a unique solution due to the existence and uniqueness theorem centred at $x=2020$. Do we use separation of variables here? 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: No separation of variables necessary, just plug in numbers. What does the DE turn into now?

Comment: Well we then get $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ so $y=k$ where $k$ is a constant. Why would there be no other solutions? Is it because of the initial value given?

Comment: Specifically which constant does $y$ have to be? Also you said it yourself why there would be no other solutions. It is up to you to prove if existence and uniqueness applies to this DE.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: Making $u = y^{-2}$ the ODE transforms to $u' = -3 e^{\sin(x+\frac 1u)}$ s. t. $u(2020)=\infty$